# Password authentication failed only when using psycopg2.extras.LogicalReplicationConnection

Tags: psycopg2

I'm using RDS IAM authentication when connecting to postgres. I use the AWS API to get a temporary token which can then just be used just like a regular password. The full token looks something like:

```
dbname.accountrdsid.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/?Action=connect&DBUser=myuser&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=1234%2Fus-west-1%2Frds-db%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211116T171155Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Security-Token=very_long_urlencoded_token&X-Amz-Signature=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I can successfully connect using this *unless* I try to set `connection_factory=psycopg2.extras.LogicalReplicationConnection` when calling `pyscopg2.connect`.

[I'm seeing failures when using this library.](https://github.com/transferwise/pipelinewise-tap-postgres/blob/ae9b211a9302c3ded42bcbfa06deccefc215dc07/tap_postgres/db.py#L41-L58) Basically, this works fine:

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(**cfg)
```

But this gets `connection to server at "dbname.accountrdsid.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (10.0.0.100), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myuser"`:

```py
cfg['connection_factory'] = psycopg2.extras.LogicalReplicationConnection
conn = psycopg2.connect(**cfg)
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions here [Logical Replication](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#replication-support) as to config settings?

Comment: I [created an issue](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1391) in the psycopg2 repo which includes a small script to recreate the issue. I could only reproduce it when using RDS IAM auth, and not when testing against a local db with my password set to one of the tokens I had generated. Given this, it does seem most likely to be a bug in RDS rather than pyscopg2 so I'll eventually open a bug with AWS and update here if there's a resolution.